# Azure data factory unable to load (binary copy) HDFS data encrypted with keys

Tags: azure, encryption, hdfs, azure-data-factory

Using HDFS Linked service and Windows credential (admin) I am able to copy data from HDFS for files which are not encrypted with keys. However it fails to load data from HDFS which is encrypted giving below error
Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to read a 'Hdfs' file. File path:abc/xyz/fgh''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.,Source=System

```
                    "source": {

                        "type": "BinarySource",

                        "storeSettings": {

                            "type": "HdfsReadSettings",

                            "recursive": true,

                            "deleteFilesAfterCompletion": false

                        },

                        "formatSettings": {

                            "type": "BinaryReadSettings"

                        }

                    },

                    "sink": {

                        "type": "BinarySink",

                        "storeSettings": {

                            "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"

                        }

                    },

                    "enableStaging": false,

                    "skipErrorFile": {

                        "dataInconsistency": false

                    },

                    "validateDataConsistency": true,

                    "logSettings": {

                        "enableCopyActivityLog": true,

                        "copyActivityLogSettings": {

                            "logLevel": "Info",

                            "enableReliableLogging": false

                        },

                     

                    }
Same user can query data directly however when using ADF (SHIR), it fails to load those datasets encrypted with keys.
```

Comment: Have you validated KMS ACLS on Encryption Zones ? Does the Client credentials being used to read hdfs data have access to EDEK, EEK? means is it authorized to decrypt data?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Same user is able to read encrypted data while logging at on prem. But not while running data factory. ANything missing on adf piece that needs to be looked at

Answer (score 0):

webExceptions, suggest Webhdfs api being used.. Can you please validate your settings against this ( specially  GENERATE_EEK and DECRYPT_EEK permissions to hdfs user, maybe remove from blacklist)

- https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.1/configuring-hdfs-encryption/content/changes_in_behavior_after_hdfs_encryption_is_enabled_webhdfs.html

  Remove the HDFS service user from the blacklist:
  KMS supports a blacklist and a whitelist for key access (through kms-acls.xml). By default the hdfs service user is included in the blacklist for decrypt_eek operations. To support WebHDFS, the HDFS service user must not be on the key access blacklist.
  To edit the blacklist using Ambari, go to Ranger KMS -> Configs, and search for "blacklist" or open the Advanced dbks-site list.
  Remove hdfs from the hadoop.kms.blacklist.DECRYPT_EEK property:

  Restart Ranger KMS.
  The HDFS service user must have GENERATE_EEK and DECRYPT_EEK permissions. To add the permissions using the Ranger Web UI, select the Access Manager tab-> Resource Based Policies (the default Access Manager view). Select the key store, select the policy, and click the edit icon. In the Permissions column click the edit icon and check the boxes for GenerateEEK and DecryptEEK. Then click Save.

  Because the HDFS service user will have access to all keys, the HDFS service user should not be the administrative user. Specify a different administrative user in hdfs-site.xml for the administrative user.